# Subscribe to child model change from Parent in Angular

Tags: angular

In my child component I have a list of `TimeZones` having a model `SelectedTimeZone(Model)`. I need to broadcast the `SelectedTimeZone` change to list of subscribers.

ChildComponent:

```
export class TimeZoneComponent implements OnInit {

  public timezones: ITimeZone[] = [];
  public SelectedTimeZone: ITimeZone;
  public SelectedTimeZone$ = new Observable<ITimeZone>();

  constructor(private timezoneService: TimeZoneService) {
  //i'm not sure what to do next since i already declare an Observable<ITimezone>();
  }

}
```

Comment: [RTFD](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event)

Comment: you are looking for `@Output` decorator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use an event emitter in child and get the output inside parent
>   component(s).

**ChildComponent.ts**

On changing timezone, trigger a function to emit output.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

export class TimeZoneComponent implements OnInit {

  public timezones: ITimeZone[] = [];
  public SelectedTimeZone: ITimeZone;

  // New event emitter
  @Output() timezoneChangeEvent = new EventEmitter<ITimeZone>();

  constructor(private timezoneService: TimeZoneService) {}

  // Trigger this function on timezone change
  onTimezoneChange(){
      // Output the selected timezone as event output
      this.timezoneChangeEvent.emit(this.SelectedTimeZone);
  }

}
```

**ParentComponent.html**

Bind the child event output to a function within parent component.

```
// Trigger a function on event output detection
<app-time-zone (timezoneChangeEvent)="changeTimezone($event)"></app-time-zone>
```

**ParentComponent.ts**

Function to be triggered on event output detection.

```
changeTimezone(timezone:ITimeZone){
    // Updated timezone will be available here as timezone.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create one service where you will declare your `BehaviorSubject` like

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TimeZoneService {

    public selectedTimeZone= new BehaviorSubject('');
    constructor() {

    }
}
```

Once your timezone is changed so from that component you need to fire the event like

```
this.timezoneService.selectedTimeZone.next(value of timezone);
```

Where you want the updated timezone value you need to subscribe to this event like

```
this.timezoneService.selectedTimeZone.subscribe((p) => {
        // p is your updated value
    });
```

Comment: this is not a better approach for child to parent communication as Angular already provided `@Output` decorator for this purpose

Comment: @Mustahsan : See what OP has asked he wants "broadcast my change to list of subscriber""

Comment: yes by using @Output he can emit any event and parent will get notified about it in its method

Comment: @Mustahsan what if I have timezone in my header component and my parent component doesn't know anything about the header because it's a separate route

Comment: parent components should know about childs, what you said is suggested in cases where there is no parent-child relation

Comment: @Mustahsan:  yes definitely there is no parent-child relation here because any application timezone will be selected once and it will be applied for all the component

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways in angular to make data transfer between two components. As you have requested for the changes to be detected by a list of subscribers, https://stackoverflow.com/a/58092434/6835898 is the perfect answer.
Other ways of data transfer are based on the relationship between two components, as in parent-child, child-parent, siblings. For smaller projects, Observables sounds like a good idea but as projects go bigger, you will have to make a dictionary for all the different Observables you will be using all over the project. And so, EventEmitters and Inputs are the best ones to use for data transfers in big projects.